# How to get value from a TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio, textbox

I change my question because it probably was not understood. Also sorry for my English...

Dynamically create TextBoxes which put them in array.

A piece of my code:

```
public partial class NewArticleForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Label[] lblName;
    private TextBox[] txtName;
    private Label[] lblSurname;
    private TextBox[] txtSurname;
    private PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1;

    public int NumberOfOtherAuthors()
    {
        Int32 index = Convert.ToInt32(NumberList.SelectedValue);
        return index;
    }

    public void dataofOtherAuthor()
    {
        int authors;
        int i = 0;
        int j=1
        authors = NumberOfOtherAuthors();
        lblName = new Label[authors];
        txtName = new TextBox[authors];
        lblSurname = new Label[authors];
        txtSurname = new TextBox[authors];
        PlaceHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();
        for (i = 0; i < authors; i++)
        {
            Label authorInformation = new Label();
            authorInformation.Text = "Information for Author " + j.ToString() + " :";
            lblName[i] = new Label();
            lblName[i].Text = "Name:";
            txtName[i] = new TextBox();
            lblSurname[i] = new Label();
            lblSurname[i].Text = "Surname:";
            txtSurname[i] = new TextBox();    
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(authorInformation);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblName[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtName[i]); 
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblSurname[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtSurname[i]);    
            // Add a spacer in the form of an HTML <BR> element.
            Panel1.Controls.Add(PlaceHolder1);
            j++;      }  }

 protected void NumberList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataofOtherAuthor();
    }

    private void UploadForm()
    {
        int numberOfOtherAuthors = NumberOfOtherAuthors();
        int i=0;

            for (i = 0; i < numberOfOtherAuthors; i++)
            { 
                Label1.Text = txtName[i].Text;       

            }
        }


    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            UploadForm();
    }
}
```

How can I get the value of textboxes??
Specifically I want to pass the data in a database. Label is a test if I get the value.

Thank you!!!

Comment: How are you getting your controls out of nel1 and thus PlaceHolder1?

Comment: just to make sure this isn't a type problem, change `String x = txtName[i].Text;` to `string x = (TextBox)(txtName[i]).Text;`

Comment: perhaps I'm mistaken, but is it possible you're accidentally overriding the string 'x' at each iteration?

Comment: I have this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: also, i dont see how txtName = new TextBox[authors] can work, if you create "authors" only the line after that. you cant use a variable before you've declared it

Comment: @jimmysnn T_T the general rule is to ALWAYS say what error you have. For example authors (when you create the array) isnt created yet and String x should be string x.

Comment: To say otherwise
I have 
private TextBox[] txtName;
int number;
For(i=0;<number;i++)
{
txtName[i] = new TextBox();
}

how to get the value for each texbox in array txtName

Comment: Asp.Net & Winform tags, now I've seen it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are aware or not, but you are placing `PlaceHolder1` in `Panel1` in every iteration of your for loop. Maybe you meant to do `Panel1.Controls.Add(PlaceHolder1);` after the for loop?
Anyway, you have placed these TextBox controls into the form. If you are trying to access them via postback, you need to either access them by their set `ID`, or access them through their asp containers (while setting `runat="server"`):

```
x = (p1.Controls[placeHolderIndex].Controls[textBoxIndex] as TextBox).Text;
```

or you could try

```
x = (p1.FindControl("placeHolder_ID").FindControl("textBox_ID") as TextBox).Text;
```

again make sure they are all `runat="server"`

`txtName` will not retain its value after a postback.

Have your second loop do something more useful than overwrite the set string as well; maybe add each value to a List

```
List<string> x = new List<string>();
for (i = 0; i < authors; i++)
{  
   x.Add((p1.Controls[placeHolderIndex].Controls[i] as TextBox).Text);
   //increment placeHolderIndex if you don't change your design
}
```

Comment: To say otherwise I have private 
TextBox[] txtName; 
int number; 
For(i=0;<number;i++) 
{ 
txtName[i] = new TextBox(); 
} how to get the value for each texbox in array txtName

Comment: Like you are doing, but `txtName` will not retain its value after a postback. You have to follow the advice I gave.

Answer (score 1):

quoting:

```
txtName = new TextBox[authors];
int authors = 5;
```

You declare `authors` AFTER creating the array, thus your error showing that `authors` doesn't exist yet and later that txtName doesn't exist (as it wasn't instantiated properly). Change it to:

```
int authors = 5;
txtName = new TextBox[authors];
```

.

Also, for correctness, change `String` to `string`,

That should do it

Comment: `System.String` and `string` are the same in C#.

Comment: @TimS. He doesnt specifically say `System.String`. Only `String` which leads to confusion. I said for correctness because string is the "default type" and helps read -> since `String` can have different meanings in certain contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add controls at correct time early enough (normally OnInit) for controls to correctly get values from the post back.

OnInit:

```
Form1.Controls.Add(myTextbox);
```

Page_Load:

```
var text = myTextbox.Text;
```

Check out [HOW TO: Dynamically Create Controls in ASP.NET by Using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794) or many other explanations on "ASP.Net how to add dynamic controls" search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the controls in the placeholder, use `Placeholder1.FindControl("`[Name of Control]`")`.

You might want to name the controls to something unique and referenceable when you are creating them.

Alternatively you can reference them with `Placeholder1.Controls(`[Index]`)` if you know the index of the control.

Answer (score 0):

I created objects using a different method from which I called `txtName[i]`, that was my issue.

```
public void dataofOtherAuthor() 
    { 
...
txtName[i] = new TextBox(); 
...}

private void UploadForm() 
    { 
...
Label1.Text = txtName[i].Text; 
...
}
```