# get value from dynamic Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I hava some arrays to save my controls. when call a function initialize arrays and  save in arrays my controls.

Code:

```
private Label[] lblName;
    private TextBox[] txtName;
    private Label[] lblSurname;
    private TextBox[] txtSurname;
    private Label[] lblInstitution;
    private TextBox[] txtInstitution;
    private Label[] lblCountry;
    private TextBox[] txtCountry;
    private Label[] lblEmail;
    private TextBox[] txtEmail;
    private PlaceHolder PlaceHolder1;


    public int NumberOfOtherAuthors()
    {
        Int32 index = Convert.ToInt32(NumberList.SelectedValue);
        return index;
    }

    public void GUIofOtherAuthor()
    {
        int authors;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;


        authors = NumberOfOtherAuthors();
        lblName = new Label[authors];
        txtName = new TextBox[authors];
        lblSurname = new Label[authors];
        txtSurname = new TextBox[authors];
        lblInstitution = new Label[authors];
        txtInstitution = new TextBox[authors];
        lblCountry = new Label[authors];
        txtCountry = new TextBox[authors];
        lblEmail = new Label[authors];
        txtEmail = new TextBox[authors];
        PlaceHolder1 = new PlaceHolder();


        for (i = 0; i < authors; i++)
        {
            Label authorInformation = new Label();
            authorInformation.Text = "Information for Author " + j.ToString() + " :";

            lblName[i] = new Label();
            lblName[i].Text = "Name:";
            txtName[i] = new TextBox();
            lblSurname[i] = new Label();
            lblSurname[i].Text = "Surname:";
            txtSurname[i] = new TextBox();
            lblInstitution[i] = new Label();
            lblInstitution[i].Text = "Institution:";
            txtInstitution[i] = new TextBox();
            lblCountry[i] = new Label();
            lblCountry[i].Text = "Country:";
            txtCountry[i] = new TextBox();
            lblEmail[i] = new Label();
            lblEmail[i].Text = "Email:";
            txtEmail[i] = new TextBox();

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span style=\"font-weight:bold;\" "));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(authorInformation);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</span>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblName[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtName[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblSurname[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtSurname[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblInstitution[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtInstitution[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblCountry[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtCountry[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblEmail[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtEmail[i]);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</table><br /> "));
            Panel1.Controls.Add(PlaceHolder1);

            j++;
        }
    }
```

Now i want to take the value of textboxes in another function `public void UploadForm(){...}`. 
I try it

```
int i;
int numberOfOtherAuthors = NumberOfOtherAuthors();

for(i=0; i<numberOfOtherAuthors; i++)
{
   String a = txtname[i].text
}
```

The Textboxes values I want to upload to the database, but let's say we save them to a string.
When i do this, i have the NullReferenceException.
So how to get the value of this textboxes???
Thanks

Comment: this is one ugly code, just use the repeater instead...

Comment: Duplicate: [How to get value from a TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808314/how-to-get-value-from-a-textbox)

Comment: sorry, but i dont found solution for this problem. if you can help me... i'm newby to c#. Thsnks

Comment: if its dynamic (create on run) and null reference exception either you dont implement the textbox as a new instance (vs does this bug sometimes-so remove and create again) or textbox.text value is null (put an if statement and msgbox to check the textbox.text to understand that is null or not) i.e. :  if(yourTextbox.Text == null){Messagebox.Show("YourTextbox doesn't have any Text") else{ //do what you want}

Comment: find a good book/resources on c#/ asp.net so you'll stopped being a newbie. shortcut answers won't help for long

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your `UploadForm()` function is referencing `txtname`, while your actual TextBox is declared as `txtName`.  Since field names are case-sensitive, the field "txtname" (lower-case 'n') is not actually defined, so it is probably the cause of your NullReferenceException in your dynamic page.