# Select a particular line in textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

[image: from1 picture] [image]I have a two forms, 1 and 2. Form1 has one textbox and form2 has a textbox and button. I want to go to a specified line, meaning that when I enter the value of form2's textbox then my mouse cursor goes to form1's textbox.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int line = Form1.ab;
  for (int i = 1; i < line; i++)
  {
      if (i == Convert.ToInt16( textBox1.Text))
      {
        // fr.textbox1 is a textbox form1 and 
        // textbox1.text is a textbox of the form1
        fr.textBox1.SelectionStart =
           int.Parse( textBox1.Text) ;
        fr.textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        break;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: i have no idea how dothis

Comment: i have used visual studio 2010.

Comment: yeah windows application not a web application

Comment: int line = Form1.ab; // this line hold a length of the textbox form1

Comment: help me any one ????????

Comment: You should state your problem better, it is unclear what you are trying to do, at least I can't. I'm sure that you would get plenty answers if you could explain your problem.

Comment: Look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739656/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specified-line-in-a-winforms-textbox-using-c).  As to HOW to get it to the other form, you will have to give the form a property that the other form can access for use.

Comment: sir i clear again my problem...I want to make my form as it is working on windows 7 simple notepad. Notepad option as GOTO line number.

Comment: i have add two picture more clear information. The first picture (top to Down) telling about the notepad and second picture after the run our program. I am writing a some line in textbox and select the edit option and then select a GO TO. when we are select the GOTO option pop new form, like that second picture.I enter the line number and select to GOTO button. That a not working proper,, plz any one help me.... thanks in advance.

Comment: @j.s.banger I expanded my answer to include how to access controls/information on other forms. Let me know if there is more specific information you need

Comment: @DiskJunky sir plz send me your personal e-mail id ...i send all my problem with fully code and with a snap shot. i have try according you but i can't. sir i have fully created a clone Notepad but i can't done this.

Comment: @j.s.banger my email is "diskjunky" at hotmail dot com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `TextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine` method finds the index of the first character of a line.
So your selection starts there. Then find the end of that line, which is `Environment.NewLine` or the end of the text.
Since the line number is entered by the user you should use `int.TryParse` to handle invalid input.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int lineNumber;
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out lineNumber) || lineNumber < 0)
    {
        textBox1.Select(0, 0);
        return;
    }

    int position = textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNumber);
    if (position < 0)
    {
        // lineNumber is too big
        textBox1.Select(textBox1.Text.Length, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        int lineEnd = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, position);
        if (lineEnd < 0)
        {
            lineEnd = textBox1.Text.Length;
        }

        textBox1.Select(position, lineEnd - position);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is correct in that it does select the visible line at the vertical line number in the textbox.  However if the textbox is set to wrap the text, and some of the lines are long enough to have wrapped, you can get a different piece of text selected from the one you intended. I resolved by changing property textBox1.WordWrap = false; as an addition you can add textBox1.ScrollToCaret(); to ensure the selected line is visible on the users screen.

Answer (score 2):

Apply this logic to your code, and recode it as you need.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (textBox_Form1.Text.Contains(textBox_Form2.Text))
                {
                    textBox_Form1.Focus();
                    textBox_Form1.SelectionStart = textBox_Form1.Text.IndexOf(textBox_Form2.Text);
                    textBox_Form1.SelectionLength = textBox_Form2.Text.Length;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like;

```
int lineNumber = Form1.ab;

// split the contents of the text box
string text = textBox1.Text;
string[] lines = text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
if (lineNumber < 0 || lineNumber > lines.Length)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The line number is does not exist");
    return;
}

// get the character pos
int selStart = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (lineNumber - 1); i++)
{
    selStart += lines[i].Length + Environment.NewLine.Length;
}
textBox1.Focus();
textBox1.SelectionStart = selStart;
textBox1.SelectionLength = lines[lineNumber - 1].Length;
```

Note: you can access the other text box directly in the other form by going to the Form2 designer, clicking the text box and going to Properties. In the Properties dialog, look for a property called Modifiers and change the value to `internal` or `public`. This will allow you to access the text box value in the other form directly like so;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2Instance = new Form2();
    string sampleText = form2Instance.textBox1.Text;
}
```

If you need to know further samples on how to access controls/details on other forms, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a NEW form1 where the textbox is likely to be blank, and calling GetPass() on that empty form. You need an instance of the already-opened form1 where the textbox might have a value. for more information

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808314/how-to-get-value-from-a-textbox)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code

```
var sdr = (System.Windows.Controls.TextBox) sender;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sdr.Text)) {
  var start = sdr.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine, sdr.CaretIndex);
  var lineIdx = sdr.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(sdr.CaretIndex);
  var lineLength = sdr.GetLineLength(lineIdx);

  sdr.SelectionStart = start + 1;
  sdr.SelectionLength = lineLength;

  sdr.SelectedText.Substring(0, sdr.SelectedText.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine) + 1);
  Clipboard.SetText(sdr.SelectedText);

}
```

Comment: While the code may answer the question, it's always good to include an explanation and relevant references when possible.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this better:

```
{
    ...
    string SelectedText = fr.textBox1.Lines[line];
    int SelectedTextPos = fr.textBox1.Text.IndexOf(SelectedText);
    int SelectedTextLen = SelectedText.Lenght;

    fr.textBox1.Select(SelectedTextPos, SelectedTextLen);
    fr.textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not good, what if textbox1 has repeated lines. Then your solution always will select the first one.